# I'm on a WhatsApp call and the person can hear my audio from YouTube etc

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger, calls

I'm using earphones and the person can hear my YouTube videos etc playing. Even blocked out the microphone. It seems the audio is being routed through the call. Any suggestions to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 2):

Try blocking "permit drawing over other apps" in YT permissions !