# Prevent person-on-call from hearing YouTube audio playing on my device

Tags: audio, calls, youtube

I would like to know why can a person hear videos playing from my Android while on call with them? How can I prevent this?

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Could you [edit] and clarify the situation: did you really play videos when on call? If yes, then the sound from your speaker might loop back to the microphone. One of the solutions is to use headphones/earphones. Otherwise, [echo cancellation](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/225245/way-to-prevent-the-noise-when-2-phones-together/225246#comment293047_225246) is another way, though I'm not sure if it's implemented on Android. Meanwhile, consider mentioning the device model and Android version too in case it's relevant.

Comment: Yes I was on a call with someone while playing a video on YouTube at the same time and they could hear what I was playing.

Comment: It seems there was an older question with a similar case: [I'm on a WhatsApp call and the person can hear my audio from YouTube etc](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/219989/44325). Consider checking the answer and let us know the result.